# std::unique_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, unique-ptr

In VC2012, I want to create a mutex in a constructor using a unique pointer and a deleter, so that I don't need to create a destructor just to call CloseHandle.

I would have thought that this would work:

```
struct foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, BOOL(*)(HANDLE)> m_mutex;
    foo() : m_mutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL), CloseHandle) {}
}
```

but on compiling I get an error:

```
error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr(void *,int 
(__cdecl *const &)(HANDLE)) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
'HANDLE' to 'void *'
```

When I modify the constructor thus:

```
foo() : m_mutex((void*)CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, 
    (name + " buffer mutex").c_str()), CloseHandle) {}
```

I get the even more unusual:

```
error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr(void *,
int (__cdecl *const &)(HANDLE)) throw()' : cannot convert 
parameter 1 from 'void *' to 'void *'
```

I'm at a loss now.  HANDLE is a typedef for void*: is there some conversion magic I need to know about?

Comment: There is a good answer to your question below, but I would seriously consider rolling my own custom owner class for a Mutex rather than exploiting std::unique_ptr's deleter for this purpose.  The fact that a HANDLE is a pointer is an implementation detail.  It could just as easily have been an index or other magic value.  Make your own RAII wrapper for it, and leave unique_ptr to manage "real" pointers.

Comment: @Adrian: I see your point.  It could also contain the RAII Wait/Release pairing in the constructor/destructor.  Cheers.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Forget about the custom deleter for now. When you say `std::unique_ptr<T>`, the `unique_ptr` constructor expects to receive a `T*`, but `CreateMutex` returns a `HANDLE`, not a `HANDLE *`.

There are 3 ways to fix this:

```
std::unique_ptr<void, deleter> m_mutex;
```

You'll have to cast the return value of `CreateMutex` to a `void *`.

Another way to do this is use [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) to get to the `HANDLE`'s underlying type.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, deleter> m_mutex;
```

Yet another way to do this is to exploit the fact that if the `unique_ptr`'s deleter contains a nested type named `pointer`, then the `unique_ptr` will use that type for its managed object pointer instead of `T*`.

```
struct mutex_deleter {
  void operator()( HANDLE h ) 
  {
    ::CloseHandle( h );
  }
  typedef HANDLE pointer;
};
std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, mutex_deleter> m_mutex;
foo() : m_mutex(::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL), mutex_deleter()) {}
```

---

Now, if you want to pass a pointer to function type as the deleter, then when dealing with the Windows API you also need to pay attention to the calling convention when creating function pointers.

So, a function pointer to [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must look like this

```
BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)
```

Combining all of it,

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, 
                BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)> m_mutex(::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL),
                                                &::CloseHandle);
```

I find it easier to use a lambda instead

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, 
                void(*)( HANDLE )> m_mutex;
foo() : m_mutex(::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL), 
                []( HANDLE h ) { ::CloseHandle( h ); }) {}
```

Or as suggested by @hjmd in the comments, use `decltype` to deduce the type of the function pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, 
                decltype(&::CloseHandle)> m_mutex(::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL),
                                                  &::CloseHandle);
```

Comment: +1 Instead of the function pointer just use decltype(&CloseHandle)

Comment: A lambda expression yields a value, not a type. I don't see how the lambda example will compile.

Comment: Blimey, I only nipped down for a spot of dinner.  I love this site.  Thanks for an excellent answer.

Comment: As well as using `decltype` to deduce the type of the function pointer, you can initialize it with `std::ptr_fun(CloseHandle)` and avoid the lambda syntax.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi You don't need a lambda or `ptr_fun`, `&::CloseHandle` works.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, true. (btw, referring to initialization of m_mutex, not the declaration of it.) May I suggest updating your answer to reflect that?

Comment: Doesn't compile with Visual C++ 2013 with Update 4.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Which part doesn't compile on VS2013?

Comment: I get the following error `unique_ptr constructed with null deleter pointer` if I try to use it like this `typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&::CloseHandle)> handle_ptr;` maybe that improper use from my part but given the solution to just use a custom deleter with a specific `typedef HANDLE pointer;` member works fine, I'm going to use that.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren That was my screw up, thanks for pointing it out. The [`unique_ptr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) that takes a `T *` argument will value initialize the deleter, and if you're using a pointer to function type as the deleter, you end up with a `nullptr`. The updated code should work, but I'd just stick with the custom deleter with the appropriate nested `pointer` type.

Comment: Note for readers: this code is only able to work because `HANDLE` is an alias for a pointer type (probably `void *`).  Similar code does not work for integer handles, because the pointer type of the unique_ptr must satisfy *NullablePointer*.

Answer (score 35):

Others have pointed out how the whole `HANDLE`/`HANDLE*` issue works. Here's a much cleverer way to deal with it, using interesting features of `std::unique_ptr`.

```
struct WndHandleDeleter
{
  typedef HANDLE pointer;

  void operator()(HANDLE h) {::CloseHandle(h);}
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, WndHandleDeleter> unique_handle;
```

This allows `unique_handle::get` to return `HANDLE` instead of `HANDLE*`, without any fancy `std::remove_pointer` or other such things.

This works because `HANDLE` is a pointer and therefore satisfies NullablePointer.

Comment: I'm slightly torn: I like the final line of Praetorian's answer as the whole solution is local, but I like your solution as it's a good piece of reuse.  I'll give you a +1!  Thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I don't know why you would want to, but I suppose you could declare a struct with no name, but with a variable declaration. Then use `decltype` to get its type. But you're not gaining anything, since either way you're inserting a name into the namespace.

Comment: @Nicol I'm thinking of a one-liner that is based off of an anonymous struct built into a templated alias.

Comment: I am not seeing this work: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1etJg3$12 -- and a quick read of the `unique_ptr` specs over at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr doesn't lead me to think that `Deleter::type::pointer` is used for `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`.  Is both gcc 4.7.2 and cppreference wrong?

Comment: @Yakk: The actual unique_ptr page on that site [clearly shows where `pointer` comes from](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr#Member_types). As for your live workspace issue, that sounds very much like a libstdc++ bug.

Comment: @Yakk: See my edit. I forgot that the `::type` is part of the template metafunction and not actually in the deleter's type. Now that makes much more sense. And the workspace compiles now. http://liveworkspace.org/code/1etJg3$13

Comment: +1 This is a very non-cryptic, easy to understand, solution, and the one I ended up using in my day-to-day make-Windows-behave header file. Thank you very much, Nicol.

Comment: +1. Also should mention that the size of this unique_ptr is the size of a pointer (because this uses a stateless deleter), unlike Praetorian's final answer which is the size of 2 pointers.

Comment: ALso, "This works because HANDLE is a pointer and therefore satisfies NullablePointer" raises the question: What should you do for handles that don't satisfy NullablePointer? Write your own RAII or write an adaptor so that it satisfies NullablePointer?

Comment: Not all `HANDLE`-based APIs use `NULL`/`nullptr` to represent an invalid handle.  Some use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you actually define unque_ptr that holds pointer to handle (HANDLE*) type, but you pass just HANDLE, not pointer to it.

Comment: Answer of Praetorian is quite full and correct, IHMO. Written in the same time I was writing.