# One-liner for RAII on non pointer?

Tags: c++, winapi, raii

**Related topic**

[std::unique_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/stdunique-ptr-deleters-and-the-win32-api)

To use a Win32 Handle as a RAII, I can use the following line

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&CloseHandle)> m_mutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL), &::CloseHandle);
```

For me this is a clean one-liner and does exactly what I want.

When it comes to SOCKET, it won't compile with this same line since SOCKET cannot be nullptr.

What I need to do to make it work is the following :

```
struct SocketDeleter
{
    typedef SOCKET pointer;

    void operator()(SOCKET h) 
    { 
        ::closesocket(h);
    }
};

// Start listen socket.
std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, SocketDeleter> sock(socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_UDP));
```

What I don't like in this implementation is that any different type of ressources I'll want to use, I'll need to copy/paste the same code to only change the closing function.

I could use a Macro, but this is really ugly and can't be used twice

```
#define RAII_UNIQUE_RESOURCE(varName, classType, init, closure)  \
struct deleterMacro                                             \
{                                                               \
    typedef classType pointer;                                  \
    void operator()(classType h)                                \
    {                                                           \
        closure(h);                                             \
    }                                                           \
};                                                              \
std::unique_ptr<classType, deleterMacro> varName(init);

// Compile, but breaks as soon as 2 sockets defined.
RAII_UNIQUE_RESOURCE(sock, SOCKET, socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_UDP), ::closesocket);
```

I tried to use a template, but I cannot pass my function pointer to the operator() function, as far as I know.

```
template<class T, class methodDeclaration, class pFuncPointer>
struct deleter
{
    typedef T pointer;

    void operator()(T h)
    {
        // Is there a way?? 
        methodDeclaration toCall = pFuncPointer;
        toCall(h);
    }
};
// With a call such as ...
std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, deleter<SOCKET, std::function<decltype(::closesocket)>, ::closesocket>> sock2(socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_UDP));
```

Comment: You'll probably want something like: `template <typename T, typename D, D Deleter> struct stateless_deleter { using pointer = T; void operator()(T x) { Deleter(x); } };` Usage: `std::unique_ptr<Socket, stateless_deleter<Socket, void(*)(Socket), &CloseSocket> p(OpenSocket());`

Comment: Why bother with `std::unique_ptr`? It will take 5 minutes to write a RAII wrapper or 30 sec to Google it up.

Comment: @Drop why write a custom functionality **if** there is a standard one?

Comment: @UmNyobe *If* there is one. As I see there is no such.

Comment: Ideas like this [have been](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3677.html) [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3830.pdf) [before](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3949.pdf).

Comment: 'this is a clean one-liner and does exactly what I want' ... And for me it is not as clear as a proper class for resource managment. 'When it comes to SOCKET, it won't compile with this same line since SOCKET cannot be nullptr' and thats one reason to write proper abstraction, it is a MUTEX, a SOCKET, a FILE, a ... but not a Pointer. unique_ptr is not a general raii class for every resource.

Comment: @fjoanis, since Kerrek SB answered in the comments instead of as an answer, feel free to make a self-answer (crediting Kerrek, of course) and remove the answer from the question.

Comment: @knivil: Actually, it doesn't have to be `nullptr`, it just has to be comparable-to `nullptr` (I think it is called _NullablePointer_). I have written a class that implements that for non-pointer-like types, if anybody is interested...

Comment: @rodrigo I'm a taker for any answer which permits me to write only one line of code for any type of ressources. I just don't want to have to declare 1 structure for each kind of resource.

Comment: @fjoanis: You could wrap the small struct in a template and specify the function as a pointer-to-function template argument. But there are problems there with the function type and IMO, it is simply not worth it: the `struct` is just 4 lines. I've posted my code as an answer.

Comment: It is like using std::tuple for every compound data. It is just wrong and would not pass code review in our company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I want with another Kerrek SB answer. It's the proposal for STD Unique Resource.

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_RESOURCE_H_
#define UNIQUE_RESOURCE_H_

#include <type_traits>

// From standard proposal http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3949.pdf
// Slightly modified to compile on VS2012.
namespace std
{
    namespace experimental
    {
        enum class invoke_it { once, again };
        template<typename R,typename D>
        class unique_resource_t 
        {
            R resource;
            D deleter;
            bool execute_on_destruction; // exposition only
            unique_resource_t& operator=(unique_resource_t const &);
            unique_resource_t(unique_resource_t const &); // no copies!
        public:
            // construction
            explicit unique_resource_t(R && resource, D && deleter, bool shouldrun=true)
                : resource(std::move(resource))
                , deleter(std::move(deleter))
                , execute_on_destruction(shouldrun)
            {

            }
            // move
            unique_resource_t(unique_resource_t &&other) /*noexcept*/
                :resource(std::move(other.resource))
                ,deleter(std::move(other.deleter))
                ,execute_on_destruction(other.execute_on_destruction)
            {
                    other.release();
            }
            unique_resource_t& operator=(unique_resource_t &&other) 
            {
                this->invoke(invoke_it::once);
                deleter=std::move(other.deleter);
                resource=std::move(other.resource);
                execute_on_destruction=other.execute_on_destruction;
                other.release();
                return *this;
            }
            // resource release
            ~unique_resource_t() 
            {
                this->invoke(invoke_it::once);
            }
            void invoke(invoke_it const strategy = invoke_it::once) 
            {
                if (execute_on_destruction) {
                    try {
                        this->get_deleter()(resource);
                    } catch(...){}
                }
                execute_on_destruction = strategy==invoke_it::again;
            }
            R const & release() /*noexcept*/{
                execute_on_destruction = false;
                return this->get();
            }
            void reset(R && newresource) /*noexcept*/ {
                invoke(invoke_it::again);
                resource = std::move(newresource);
            }
            // resource access
            R const & get() const /*noexcept*/ {
                return resource;
            }
            operator R const &() const /*noexcept*/ 
            {
                return resource;
            }
            R operator->() const /*noexcept*/ 
            {
                return resource;
            }

//             Couldn't make this function compile on VS2012
//             std::add_lvalue_reference<std::remove_pointer<R>::type>::type operator*() const 
//             {
//                     return * resource;
//             }

            // deleter access
            const D & get_deleter() const /*noexcept*/ 
            {
                return deleter;
            }
        };

        //factories
        template<typename R,typename D>
        unique_resource_t<R,D> unique_resource( R && r,D t) /*noexcept*/ 
        {
                return unique_resource_t<R,D>(std::move(r), std::move(t),true);
        }
            template<typename R,typename D>
        unique_resource_t<R,D>
            unique_resource_checked(R r, R invalid, D t ) /*noexcept*/ {
                bool shouldrun = (r != invalid);
                return unique_resource_t<R,D>(std::move(r), std::move(t), shouldrun);
        }
    }
}
#endif /* UNIQUE RESOURCE H */
```

Usage

```
auto listenSocket = std::experimental::unique_resource_checked(socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP), INVALID_SOCKET, closesocket);
```

Hope this makes std soon enough!

Comment: It did not make it into C++17 unfortunately, but [the proposal is still active](http://wg21.link/p0052)

Answer (score 13):

It is well known the example to RAII a `FILE*` using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
struct FILEDeleter
{
    typedef FILE *pointer;
    void operator()(FILE *fp) { fclose(fp); }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<FILE, FILEDeleter> FilePtr;

FilePtr f(fopen("file.txt", "r"));
```

Alas, a similar approach to POSIX `close()` to RAII a file descriptor is not possible:

```
struct FDDeleter
{
    typedef int pointer;
    void operator()(int fd) { close(fp); }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<int, FDDeleter> FD;
```

Although some compilers will work just fine, it is not valid because the `fd==0` is a valid file descriptor! The null one should be `-1`. But anyway, even if it were `0` it is still not valid, because `FDDeleter::pointer` shall satisfy the requirements of *NullablePointer* (summing up):

1. It shall be comparable to `nullptr`.
2. It shall be value-initialized to a value that compares equal to `nullptr`.

Thus, `UniqueHandle` is born!

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T, T TNul = T()>
class UniqueHandle
{
public:
    UniqueHandle(std::nullptr_t = nullptr)
        :m_id(TNul)
    { }
    UniqueHandle(T x)
        :m_id(x)
    { }
    explicit operator bool() const { return m_id != TNul; }

    operator T&() { return m_id; }
    operator T() const { return m_id; }

    T *operator&() { return &m_id; }
    const T *operator&() const { return &m_id; }

    friend bool operator == (UniqueHandle a, UniqueHandle b) { return a.m_id == b.m_id; }
    friend bool operator != (UniqueHandle a, UniqueHandle b) { return a.m_id != b.m_id; }
    friend bool operator == (UniqueHandle a, std::nullptr_t) { return a.m_id == TNul; }
    friend bool operator != (UniqueHandle a, std::nullptr_t) { return a.m_id != TNul; }
    friend bool operator == (std::nullptr_t, UniqueHandle b) { return TNul == b.m_id; }
    friend bool operator != (std::nullptr_t, UniqueHandle b) { return TNul != b.m_id; }

private:
    T m_id;
};
```

Its use is pretty easy, best seen with an example:

```
struct FDDeleter
{
    typedef UniqueHandle<int, -1> pointer;
    void operator()(pointer p)
    {
        close(p);
    }
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<int, FDDeleter> FD;

FD fd(open("test.txt", O_RDONLY));
```

If you truly want a one-liner you could go with this generalization:

```
template <typename T, T TNul = T(), typename RD, RD (*D)(T)>
struct OLDeleter
{
    typedef UniqueHandle<T, TNul> pointer;
    void operator()(pointer p)
    {
        D(p);
    }
};
```

And then just one line:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, OLDeleter<int, -1, int, close> > FD fd(open("test.txt", O_RDONLY));
```

The problem is that you must add the return of `close()` as a template argument and assume that there isn't anything funny about this function that prevents its conversion to a `int(*)(int)` (weird calling conventions, extra parameters, macros...) and that is quite inconvenient.

You could add a function wrapper:

```
void my_close(int fd) { close(fd); }
```

But if you are into it, you could as well write the whole `struct FDDeleter`.

Answer (score 5):

Kerrek SB answered in the comments and it was exactly what I was looking for!

```
template <typename T, typename D, D Deleter> 
struct stateless_deleter 
{
    typedef T pointer; 

    void operator()(T x) 
    { 
        Deleter(x); 
    } 
};
std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, stateless_deleter<SOCKET, int(*)(SOCKET), &::closesocket>> listenSocket(socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_UDP));
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't realize `unique_ptr` checked for a `pointer` type policy from its deleter.  Neat.

Comment: But this is only valid if `T` is is a pointer type. If not, it will not satisfy the `unique_ptr` requirements of _NullablePointer_. And IIRC, Windows `SOCKET` is a typedef of `int` or `long`, and those do not qualify.

Comment: This code is ill-formed ; *NullablePointer* requires amongst other things that `x != nullptr` be valid (where `x` has the type of `D::pointer`)

Answer (score 3):

I often use this in C++11:

```
 #include <utility>

 namespace{
    template<typename F>
    struct RAII_Helper{
        template<typename InitFunction>
        RAII_Helper(InitFunction &&init, F &&exit) : f_(std::forward<F>(exit)), canceled(false){
            init();
        }
        RAII_Helper(F &&f) : f_(f), canceled(false){
        }
        ~RAII_Helper(){
            if (!canceled)
                f_();
        }
        void cancel(){
            canceled = true;
        }
    private:
        F f_;
        bool canceled;
    };
 }
 template<class F>
 RAII_Helper<F> RAII_do(F &&f){
    return RAII_Helper<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
 }

 template<class Init, class Exit>
 RAII_Helper<Exit> RAII_do(Init &&init, Exit &&exit){
    return RAII_Helper<Exit>(std::forward<Init>(init), std::forward<Exit>(exit));
 }
```

usage:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file", "r");
if (!f)
    return "error";
auto filecloser = RAII_do([=]{fclose(f);});

//also makes for good init / exit objects
static auto initExit = RAII_do([]{initializeLibrary();}, []{exitLibrary();});
```

I like it because it works for arbitrary code, not just pointers or handles. Also the cancel function could be omitted if never used.

Comment: Your class misses move operators or you'll be able to copy it leading to double free/close/release!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution using as an example the NetCDF C API, which has plain ints as handles:

```
retval = nc_open(..., &id);
...  // validate
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> always_be_closing(&id, [](int* p){nc_close(*p);});
```

Of course you can check the value in the lambda, if necessary.

```
... [](int* p){ if(p) nc_close(*p); }
```

And a typedef makes it a little nicer:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> nc_closer;
...
nc_closer abc(&id, [](int* p){nc_close(*p);});
```

And you probably want a function to reduce duplication:

```
static void nc_close_p(int* p) { nc_close(*p); }
...
nc_closer abc(&id, &nc_close_p);
```

or:

```
auto abc = auto_nc_close(&id, &nc_close_p);
```

Since `unique_ptr` implements `operator bool`, you can also use this as a block scope, like `using` in C#:

```
if (auto abc = auto_nc_close(&id, &nc_close_p))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach (within the premises of the RAII idiom though) is to use **boost's scope exit**.

Example :

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

int main() 
{
    std::FILE* f = std::fopen("example_file.txt", "w");
    assert(f);

    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(f) {
    // Whatever happened in scope, this code will be
    // executed  and  file  will be correctly closed.
        std::fclose(f);
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    // Some code that may throw or return.
    // ...
}
```

Using [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) functionality, you'd be practically specifying freestanding "RAII destructor actions". Use where it makes your code clearer and cleaner and avoid when all functionality would be more easily incorporated (or already is) inside a class' destructor.

---

It seems that [soon](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3677.html) **additional RAII functionality** will be added to the language. When available you'll be able to use something like `scoped_resource` which looks like [**this**](http://www.andrewlsandoval.com/scope_exit/scoped_resource.h) (I'd refer to that link for a full fledged implementation of what you ask)