# Wrap an opaque pointer in a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, std, shared-ptr, winsock2

I'm trying to implement a simple TCP server application using winsock2. To this end I have a class that accepts connections (`TcpServer`) and a class that handles connections (`TcpListener`). To this end these objects need to share `SOCKET`, whis is defined as `UINT_PTR`. To safely share this a `shared_ptr` seems to be the way to go. Unfortunately it seems that a `shared_ptr` should wrap a `struct` or `class`, hence my implementation below.

```
struct SafeSocket_
{
    SOCKET Socket;
    SafeSocket_(SOCKET socket)
        : Socket(socket)
    {}
    ~SafeSocket_()
    {
        closesocket(Socket);
        std::cout << "destroyed SafeSocket_" << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<SafeSocket_> SafeSocket;
```

To create/accept a new socket I use the following horrible code. What's worse even is that I need to use `ClientSocket->Socket` all over the place.

```
SafeSocket ClientSocket = SafeSocket(new SafeSocket_(accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL)));
```

There must be a better way of handling this besides using a nice wrapper library.

Note: I'm aware there are nice wrapper libraries likes asio from boost, but I'm just messing around to get my head around some of the C++ basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that `UINT_PTR` isn't an opaque pointer.  It's an integer.  If it was `typedef struct __socket SOCKET;`, then you could just write `std::shared_ptr<decltype(*SOCKET{})>`, stick in a custom deleter to call close_socket, and you'd be laughing.

There are a number of possible approaches:

- Make `SafeSocket` be a class which contains the shared_ptr, and which has a `socket` member function.  Then you write `ClientSocket.socket()` all over the place.
- As above, but give `SafeSocket` versions of the socket functions, and it provides the actual socket argument.  So instead of `read( ClientSocket.Socket, ...)` you write `ClientSocket.read(...)`.
- Revert to `SafeSocket`as a typedef, but put the additional functions in `SafeSocket_`, so you write `ClientSocket->read(...)`

I think I prefer the middle solution best.

Comment: Good lord!  It's taken three edits to get that nearly right!

Comment: It is possible to [have a `SOCKET` in a `std::unique_ptr`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer) using a custom `Deleter` that defines `SOCKET` as the `pointer` type even though it is not really a pointer. Not sure if the same can be done with `std::shared_ptr`, though it does support a custom `Deleter` as well, but maybe or maybe not custom pointers? I haven't dug into it to look yet.

Comment: I chose the middle solution. What Remy suggests would be nice, but I now realise it would be confusing to wrap a resource number in a pointer container.