# Unique Pointer to non-pointer compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I tried to implement unique pointers to non-pointer as described here:
[One-liner for RAII on non pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer) and https://dzone.com/articles/c11-smart-pointers-are-not . But I always get an compiler error: /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:235:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘unsigned int’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’ to binary ‘operator!=’

This is my code:

```
struct ShaderDeleter
{
    typedef GLuint pointer; // Note the added typedef
    void operator()(GLuint shader) {
        glDeleteShader(shader);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<GLuint, ShaderDeleter> smart_shader{glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)};
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04

Compiler: g++

Comment: What happens if you simply comment out the `typedef`?

Comment: Compiler error: Test.cpp:26:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<unsigned int, ShaderDeleter>::unique_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the typedef. According to the linked SO question and article, you should be able to use unique_ptr also for non-pointer types if you use a typedef for pointer in the deleter.

Comment: The article appears to be wrong, as explained in the SO answers you linked. Even if you change `T` in the deleter, it still must satisfy the NullablePointer concept, which is why the code from you or the article [will not work](https://godbolt.org/g/9G22dm): You can't compare a `GLuint` to `nullptr`, which is exactly what the `unique_ptr` constructor does.

Comment: It would be a better idea to wrap `GLuint` into a dedicated wrapper which will also prevent mixing of unrelated values (`GLuint` for shader and `GLuint` for buffer for example).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try a new way then. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to C++17 [unique.ptr.single]/3:

> [...]  The type `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall satisfy the requirements of `NullablePointer`.

Those requirements are found in [nullablepointer.semantics], which is [summarised here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NullablePointer). In brief, the type must allow comparison to `nullptr`.  So an integer cannot be used as the type.

The code in your non-SO link is ill-formed. The code in the answer by "fjoanis" in the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer) is also ill-formed.

---

Instead, you could use one of the other solutions to that question. IMHO `unique_ptr` is not suitable for this task. There is [a proposal P0052](http://wg21.link/p0052) for something called `std::unique_resource` designed for this purpose.

I will probably get downvoted for mentioning this, but perhaps you could try using `void *` as the pointer type , and casting the GLuint to `void *`.  In general such a cast is non-portable and may cause a runtime exception, but on common x86 platforms you probably get away with it. [Link to example that compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/6dWdUp).

Comment: Instead of going into the dragons territory and dealing with possible [fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=DF2014:Fun&redirect=yes), maybe it would be possible and relatively easy to provide a lightweight nullable box something like [here](https://godbolt.org/g/8Yrrs1) I am thinking of making a supplementary answer to yours with the code, so it's easily accessible on-site. I used `int` but it should be easy enough to translate it to `GLuint` or template the type and the null value. It seems to work as expected.

Comment: @luk32 maybe you could post it on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer)