# Specifying custom default deleter for std::unique_ptr with typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I've got a C code, working with some resources. It has functions like

```
ResourcePointer resource_new(void);
void resource_delete(ResourcePointer *res);
```

where `ResourcePointer` is

```
typedef void * ResourcePointer;
```

I would like to create a `typedef` for `std::unique_ptr`, specifying that custom default deleter.

The following works, but requires repeating `resource_delete`.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<ResourcePointer>::type, 
                            void(*)(ResourcePointer)> Resource_auto_pointer;
```

and later in the code

```
Resource_auto_pointer resource(resource_new(), resource_delete);
...
Resource_auto_pointer res2 = { resource_new(), resource_delete };
```

How should I change `typedef`, so that compiler would automatically substitute `resource_delete` every time it is needed?
I want my code to look like the following

```
Resource_auto_pointer2 resource (resource_new());
...
Resource_auto_pointer2 res2 = { resource_new() };
```

The compiler should somehow guess that it should call `resource_delete` for each object of type `Resource_auto_pointer2`.

I work in MS Visual Studio 2013.

**Update**
I've read answers to other similar questions. 
I don't understand two things.

1. Why std::function doesn't work?
2. why should I create new types, since (presumably) everything is said already?

Comment: Define your own function `std::unique_ptr<void, void(&)(void*)> make_resource() { return std::unique_ptr<void, void(&)(void*)>(resource_new(), resource_delete); }`? [Example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h)

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::unique\_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/stdunique-ptr-deleters-and-the-win32-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a function object that calls the right function:

```
struct resource_deleter
{
  using pointer = std::remove_pointer<ResourcePointer>::type;
  void operator()(ResourcePointer p) const { resource_delete(p); }
};

using res_ptr = std::unique_ptr<resource_deleter::pointer, resource_deleter>;
```

Now you don't need to pass the deleter to the `unique_ptr` constructor, because the deleter can be default-constructed and will do the right thing:

```
res_ptr p{ resource_new() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas, including C++20 lambda in unevaluated context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

using HANDLE = std::byte*;

HANDLE make_HANDLE() { static auto k_h = HANDLE{}; return ++k_h; } // AKA Win32's CreateFile etc
void close_HANDLE(HANDLE h) { std::cout << "HANDLE_close(" << h << ")" << std::endl; } // AKA Win32's CloseHandle etc

#if __cplusplus >= 202002 // C++20; using lambda in unevaluated context
using HANDLE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<
    std::remove_pointer_t<HANDLE>,
    decltype([](HANDLE h) { close_HANDLE(h); })>;
#else
[[maybe_unused]] inline static auto HANDLE_deleter = [](HANDLE h) { close_HANDLE(h); };
using HANDLE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<HANDLE>, decltype(HANDLE_deleter)>;
#endif

int main()
{
    auto h1 = HANDLE_ptr(make_HANDLE());
    auto h2 = HANDLE_ptr(make_HANDLE());
    auto h3 = HANDLE_ptr(make_HANDLE());
    std::cout << h1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << h2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << h3 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my question. `std::unique_ptr` requires types in instantiation, while address of `resource_delete` function is a constant. One needs to create a `struct` or a `class` to convert it to type.