# Get memory address output function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to work all winapi with standart c++. how to pass output with address? look **o_processName**. **GetModuleFileNameExW** function paremeter 3 need wchar_t type. i need to convert it to wstring type. as i search the possible is to pass memory address to **GetModuleFileNameExW** not the type.

```
void GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId, std::wstring *o_processName)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL)
    {
        if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, &o_processName, MAX_PATH))
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I want to work all winapi with standart c++*" - that's not possible. WinAPI is **not** standard `C++`

Comment: `&o_processName` is a pointer to `o_processName`, which already is a pointer and will therefore have the type `std::wstring**`. Not really what  [`GetModuleFileNameExW` ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa) expect. Never forget to read the documentation of the functions you use.

Comment: even in documentation of this api clear stated - if you need path of exe - not use it. To retrieve the name of the main executable module for a remote process, use the `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName` function.

Comment: i check all windows api need to input buffer MAX_PATH. is there ways to check process name without input the buffer.

Comment: *all windows api need to input buffer MAX_PATH* - of course no. *is there ways to check process name without input the buffer* - you want that api allocate buffer yourself and return it to you ? some api do this, but not for query exe name. in what problem allocate buffer ? and again - `GetModuleFileNameExW` - wrong api here

Comment: and `CloseHandle(hProcess);` need call if `hProcess != NULL` - even if `GetModuleFileNameExW` or any another code inside fail

Comment: by the way, u knows api to get process name by pid? like **notepad.exe**.

Comment: GetProcessImageFileName return device path process. and queryfullprocess return path too. i just need the name process.

Comment: if you want name without path - simply search for last \ - nothing can be more simply.

Comment: and from where you get pid (i_processId) ?

Comment: there's function that i create. i need this function to work. is there condition i need t his function.

Comment: @RbMn in no way do I disagree with the information you have stated, but I would like to add everyone starts somewhere and we all took baby steps to get where we are with our own win32 API knowledge. I find, quite often, that telling someone that they are doing things incorrectly without providing them a clear solution simply is counter productive to the ethos of SO.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a `std::wstring` (or any C++ container) *directly* to a Win32 API function.  The Win32 API is written with a C interface, and so it knows nothing about C++ types.  As such, you must use C semantics when calling the API.

In your example, you can allocate a C style `WCHAR[]` buffer to receive the filename, and then assign that buffer to your `std::wstring`:

```
void GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId, std::wstring *o_processName) {
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwLength = 0;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        dwLength = GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    o_processName->assign(szFileName, dwLength);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a C++ container, you have to preallocate it and then pass its internal data buffer to the API:

```
void GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId, std::wstring *o_processName) {
    std::wstring wFileName;
    wFileName.resize(MAX_PATH);
    DWORD dwLength = 0;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        dwLength = GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, &wFileName[0], MAX_PATH); // or wFileName.data() in C++17 and later
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    o_processName->assign(wFileName.c_str(), dwLength);
}
```

```
void GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId, std::wstring *o_processName) {
    std::vector<WCHAR> vecFileName(MAX_PATH, 0);
    DWORD dwLength = 0;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        dwLength = GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, &vecFileName[0], MAX_PATH); // or vecFileName.data() in C++11 and later
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    o_processName->assign(&vecFileName[0], dwLength); // or vecFileName.data()
}
```

```
void GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId, std::wstring *o_processName) {
    std::array<WCHAR, MAX_PATH> arrFileName;
    DWORD dwLength = 0;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        dwLength = GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, arrFileName.data(), MAX_PATH);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    o_processName->assign(arrFileName.data(), dwLength);
}
```

If you want, you can take this a step further by [using `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 and later to ensure the `HANDLE` is closed automatically when it goes out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/).

And lastly, you should be using [`GetProcessImageFileNameW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew) instead of [`GetModuleFileNameExW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw):

> To retrieve the name of the main executable module for a remote process, use the `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName` function. This is more efficient and more reliable than calling the `GetModuleFileNameEx` function with a NULL module handle.

Also, because `GetProcessImageFileName()` requires only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access rights, which you are more likely to be able to obtain than `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` rights, especially for system/restricted processes.

Comment: This fixes the potential handle leak in the original code, but introduces new potential handle leaks. Both [assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) and [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) can throw. If they do, `hProcess` is never released.

Comment: this code does not show thw OP how to use a standard container with win32 API, which is what the OP specifically asked for.

Comment: @joh: The code demonstrates precisely that. Specifically, which part do you disagree with? Minus the exception safety issue, this is precisely, how one would do it.

Comment: @inspectable specifically how to use a wstring with win32 API.

Comment: @IInspectable specifically , and i quote, " i need to convert it to wstring type. as i search the possible is to pass memory address to GetModuleFileNameExW not the type."

Comment: @joh: You lost me. The code demonstrates precisely, how to interface with C code, using standard C++ containers. Again, *specifically*, where do you feel the code provided in this answer is wrong/inaccurate/doesn't address the question/something else?

Comment: @IInspectable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361844/openprocess-the-handle-is-invalid-closehandle-not-work. possible duplicate?

Comment: I fixed the handle leak on throw, and added more examples of using various C++ containers to get the filename