# I have no idea what this C++ one-liner does

Tags: c++

I found on Github a function with a pretty weird one-liner inside:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, void(*)(HANDLE)> hDevice{h, [](HANDLE handle){CloseHandle(handle);}};
```

As a person who never dealt with c++ I have no idea what it does.

I suppose, here are two nested anonymous functions connected somehow with `std::remove_pointer` and `std::unique_ptr` calls. I see an WinAPI `CloseHandle` call in the inner function and suppose that I should start my analysis with it. I cannot say more.

May be here are two nested generics.

The use of curly braces and a "bigger than" symbol also seems pretty strange to me. It breaks all the canonical cases I know.

Please help to understand this conglomerate. I do not know how to google its parts.

Comment: that's a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) with a custom deleter. Ref. eg. : [How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique\_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member)

Comment: `a "bigger than" symbol` so you aren't even familiar with templates?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I am trying to convert it to Delphi because accordingly to description the function does what I need.

Comment: Research terms: class template, type trait, function pointer, lambda expression. 
 Honestly though, it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I recommend writing code from scratch rather than translating between unrelated languages. Even if you succeed the wrong idioms will be applied

Comment: Also see: [std::unique_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/)

Comment: @KamilCuk "*so you aren't even familiar with templates?*" - Delphi has [Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Generics_Index), which are similar to C++ templates, and also use angle brackets when declaring and instantiating Generic types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First let's format it so it's readable:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, void(*)(HANDLE)> hDevice{
   h,
   [](HANDLE handle) { CloseHandle(handle); }
};
```

This is a declaration of an object called `hDevice`, initialised with two arguments. One is `h` and the other is a [lambda function](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lambdas-in-c11/240168241). We'll come back to that.

The object's type is `std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, void(*)(HANDLE)>`. The `<>` mean that this is an instantiation of a template. The template in question is [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), a standard component for memory management, a smart pointer.

Two things:

- `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a type of pointer to objects of type `T`.
- `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` is a type of pointer to objects of type `T` with custom "deleter" of type `D`; we'll come back to that.

Your `T` is `std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type`. Windows gives us the type alias [`HANDLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902987/560648) which is an obfuscated pointer type. This expression gives us the type of the thing that a `HANDLE` points to (and does so in a nice generic way that doesn't have to hardcode the result; Microsoft could change the definition of `HANDLE` and, as long as it is still a pointer, this'll still work).

Your `D` is `void(*)(HANDLE)`. That's the type of a function pointer, a pointer to a function taking `HANDLE` and returning `void`. Oh, that looks familiar: it's a function pointer type compatible with the lambda you gave as the constructor parameter.

That's because the lambda *is* the custom deleter. It tells the `unique_ptr` what to do when the smart pointer goes out of scope. Usually that'd just be a nice `delete`, but here we have a Windows API function ([`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle)) to call instead, which does the cleanup for us. This may involve a `delete` and other things, or it may involve just other things. Point is this is the proper way to close a `HANDLE`.

Overall, what's going on is that this declaration creates a `std::unique_ptr` that *takes ownership* of a `HANDLE h`, and ensures that `CloseHandle(h)` is invoked when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

**tl;dr: It's a way to add [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to a Windows handle.**